# Most of the code is still under bundle.js after code splitting with webpack

Tags: reactjs, webpack, optimization, code-splitting

[image]

I have 2 main routes for my app: admin and homepage. The admin part of the app is bloated with code, so I don't want the code only used on the admin parts to be sent to the end user.

I set up code splitting, and as you can see some of the code is correctly put under different bundles and only loads on /admin routes. However some other modules, like devextreme/esm in this example, is still being sent with the main bundle.js although it's only used and imported in /admin routes.

I import components under src/components folder to the admin page, and those components import devextreme. I don't know if this is the reason, and if it is, i don't know how to fix it.

I am using webpack 5.74, React 18.2

Thanks.